# How do I make 2 column list

Tags: c#

So currently I have an assignment where I input the students names and grades and create a 2 column list where each name is paired with a grade. Currently I am having issues creating the list it only prints out one of the students and one of the grades. I created an array with a size of 26, but only used 5 just to test it out and save time.
Here is the code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the grade book input the student and grades \n");

        string[] students = new string[26];
        string names = "";
        int grd = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Names \t\t Grades");

        for (int inc = 1; inc <= 26; inc+=2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the names");
            for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
            {

                names = Console.ReadLine();
                students[x] = names;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the grades");
            bool valid;
            for (int scr = 1; scr <= 5; scr++)
            {
                do
                {
                    valid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out grd);
                    if (!valid || grd > 100 || grd < 0)
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a grade between 0-100");
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Your grade is {0}", grd);
                } while (!valid || grd > 100 || grd < 0);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(names + "\t\t {0}", grd);
        }
```

Comment: you have the `for` loops for getting the names and grades nested inside of another for loop.  what is the purpose of the `for` loop that goes from 1 to 26?  And in your `Console.WriteLine()` you are just passing it one name and one grade so that's all it will print out.  Another note, you should start your indexes in the `for` loops at 0 since arrays are indexed starting at 0.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that the very outer loop is to print out the list of the names and grades in 2 columns for up to 26 students, but for now I am just doing 5 to save some time when I test it. I thought that the Console.WriteLine() at the very end would print it the list. How would I go about this?

Comment: well if you look at the `names` variable and the `grd` variable, they just have the last name and grade that was entered (the name when `x` equaled 5 and the grade when `src` equaled 5).

Comment: Ah so the Console.WriteLine() is only printing that last thing that I have inputted. I also realized that the very outer for loop doesn't do anything it just makes me repeat and reenter values again. How would I print all the names and grades I entered and put them in neat lists?

Answer (score 0):

To print everything you need to loop through the names and grades arrays as shown below.  You should also utilize index 0 of the arrays otherwise you will run into an issue when you try to put the 26th item in them.

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the grade book input the student and grades \n");
string[] students = new string[26];
int[] grades = new int[26]; // make an array for the grades
string names = "";
int grd = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Names \t\t Grades");
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the names");
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) // start at index 0 and go to index 4, arrays start with index 0
{
    names = Console.ReadLine();
    students[x] = names;
}

Console.WriteLine("Please enter the grades");
bool valid;
for (int scr = 0; scr < 5; scr++)
{
    do
    {
        valid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out grd);
        if (!valid || grd > 100 || grd < 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a grade between 0-100");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Your grade is {0}", grd);
    } while (!valid || grd > 100 || grd < 0);
    grades[src] = grd; // save the valid grade in the grades array
}

// to print the names and grades you must loop through each index of the array
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
// EDIT: need to access the students array here 
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t{1}", students[i], grades[i]);
}
```

Comment: Oh I see I need another separate loop to print the names and grades. I ran into a new issue, it is able to print the grades in order, but it prints the names weirdly. 

so when I input Adam with grades 10,20,30, 1 it prints it like this
(A    10)
(D    20)
(A    30)
(M    1)

Comment: it prints the name Adam separately like A, D, A, M in a list and doesn't print the names before it

Comment: Oh ok I accidentally accessed `names` not the `students` array in the final loop, see my edit.  Does each person have multiple grades?  If so you are probably better off using a `Dictionary<string, int[5]>`